# Add remove currency formatting in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I use

```
func formatAmount(number:NSNumber) -> String {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!
}
```

for changing the number to currency formatted string, but I need to remove the formatting and get just number, I need to remove the comma and currency symbol. is there any specific way? Please let me know.

I tried

```
func removeFormatAmount(string:String) -> NSNumber {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .NoStyle
    formatter.currencySymbol = .None
    formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = .None
    return formatter.numberFromString(string)!
}
```

and this gives me nil value.

**UPDATE**
I figured out that if text does not contain $ sign then formatting with currency will give nil value so what I did is

```
if string.containsString("$") {
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
}
return formatter.numberFromString(string)?.floatValue
```

now it just gives me good result.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Give some examples of how you would call your functions and what you want them to return. Also please fix the formatting of your `removeFormatAmount` function.

Comment: here is explanation: I flip the text in textView when it is touched. if textview does not have "$" then formatAmount, else I need to get plain number/string if it has $ or ",".

Comment: Please edit your question to include some examples. Examples work better than explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a string extension to do that

For Swift 3:

```
extension String {
    func removeFormatAmount() -> Double {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ","

        return formatter.number(from: self) as Double? ?? 0
     }
}
```

To use:

```
let currencyString = "$1,000.00"
let amount = currencyString.removeFormatAmount() // 1000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func formatAmount(number:NSNumber) -> String{
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.currencySymbol = ""                  // <--------
    formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ""       // <--------
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!
}
```

Comment: I am doing this. and it returns nil
func removeFormatAmount(string:String) -> NSNumber{
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .NoStyle
        formatter.currencySymbol = .None
        formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = .None
        return formatter.numberFromString(string)!
    }

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+**

This removes currency format from all languages

```
    extension String {
        public func removeFormatAmount() -> Double {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale.current
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.currencySymbol = Locale.current.currencySymbol
            formatter.decimalSeparator = Locale.current.groupingSeparator
            return formatter.number(from: self)?.doubleValue ?? 0.00
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
let currencyString = "$100.00"
let amount = currencyString.removeFormatAmount() // 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumberFormatter` has a function `numberFromString` that you can use

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

if let number = formatter.numberFromString(string) {
    //Use number
}
```

If you want the string from number it's easy to just build a string from that number afterwards

```
var number = formatter.numberFromString(string)!
var string = "\(number)"
```

Comment: He wants to get a formatted string containing just the number with no commas or currency symbols. He doesn't want to parse a string.

Comment: He wrote that he wants just the number but your answer still adds formatting in form of extra decimals.

Comment: I formatted before, so I need to remove the formatting, so just need plain number, doesn't matters if it is string or number in return.

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeFormatAmount(string:String) -> NSNumber{
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    // specify a locale where the decimalSeparator is a comma
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
    return formatter.numberFromString(string) ?? 0
}


removeFormatAmount("$15,99")    // 15.99
```